# Reading SQL FileTable data in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am currently working on a project creating a relational database that in additional to standard data also requires the ability to have attachments that relate to each record.

The database itself will be based in Microsoft SQL Server, with Microsoft Access (2016) serving as the front end.

After receiving some advice from a previous question, I believe utilizing a FileTable would be best for this.

The idea would be that the automatically generated ID for each record would automatically insert a corresponding directory to the file table, which could then be accessed by the user to drop or read files from.

I was able to set up the FileTable, and as long as I am using it through SSMS or the directory it works fine.

The idea for this I think should work, but I am having a few issues:

- I am pretty sure I need to set the connection between Access and SQL as OLEDB instead of ODBC, but I cannot seem to find a straightforward way to do this in Access. I was able to figure out how to list the provider etc., but not sure where to put it.
- Maybe related to the previous point, but I am not able to load the table in a way that allows for it to be edited. Ideally I am thinking it would work by inserting the ID as 'is_directory = 1' to the table whenever a unique ID is made, but Access does not seem to like that the filepath (large binary object) is the key.

These are the errors I am seeing:

- When trying to load the filetable itself via ODBC connection:
  'Invalid field definition 'path_locator' in definition of index or
  relationship.'

  When trying to access the file_stream/path_locator in Access: 'A
  problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communicating with the
  OLE server or ActiveX Control. Close the OLE server and restart it
  outside of Microsoft Access. Then try the original operation again in
  Microsoft Access.'

Any help on this would be appreciated, if there is anything I can clarify please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by 'insert a corresponding directory into the file table'? Is this just a path string in a text field? Or are you actually embedding file objects in table?

Comment: Basically inserting a row into the file table where the 'name' would be the unique ID for the record from the main table, and indicating that this value would be a directory. In SQL when I tested "INSERT INTO FileTable (name, is_directory) VALUES('folder_name', '1') it created an empty folder with whatever name I had written in the directory.

I am basically looking to connect to the table so that I can A. Implement that 'Insert' statement from Access, and then ideally let users click on a link that will open that folder for them to drop or view files.

Comment: I am confused. How does an INSERT sql create an empty folder? Exactly what is issue - Access establishing connection with SQLServer? In Access, a 'clickable' field would be a Hyperlink type, otherwise use VBA FollowHyperlink function to open a folder with path string.

Comment: Okay, am reading about SQLServer FileTable. Not sure Access can handle. Not finding anything. Sorry, beyond my experience.

Comment: I am trying to use a FieldTable in SQL to connect to Access.

In a SQL FieldTable, each row corresponds to files or folders in a filesystem directory.

You can either physically drag and drop items to the folder, and then they automatically appear in the table, or if you do the INSERT statement I described above you can also create an empty folder.

The end idea would be to access this information through a hyperlink, but I was hoping to be able to more directly tie the Filetable so that on the SQL side there is a clear connection between the files and the associated records.

Comment: No worries June, thanks anyways.

Comment: FileTables are not supported by Access.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing a little bit of a workaround on this.

Basically, I used the following vba code to make it so Access will automatically make a directory with the name of the ID (unless it already exists), and then open that same directory.

This achieves the same thing I was trying to accomplish without the need to connect to the FileTable directly.

The function creates a new directory at the designated string. The button click command uses that function with the designated parent directory, with the new folder being named after the Unique Identifier of the current record (if it does not exist). It then opens that folder so attachments etc. can be added.

```
Sub MakeFolder(strPath As String)
    If Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) > vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MkDir strPath
End Sub

Private Sub Command5_Click()
 MakeFolder "\\ServerName\MSSQLSERVER\FileStream\DocumentStore\" & Me.ID
 Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & "\\ServerName\MSSQLSERVER\FileStream\DocumentStore\" & Me.ID, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

The end result is then present on the SQL FileTable as I originally wanted.